# Python- Integrating an expression

Tags: python, expression

I am doing a project on Options Pricing, where I came up with this formula of American Call option. I am not able to code this formula in python. Sup here stands for supremum. Please guide me how to code this one.
[image: Formula to be coded]

This example can be used to check the code:
Assume that a stock is presently selling for a price 0
Y = 30 , the riskless interest rate r = 8% per annum, m = 0.1 ,
a = 0.06 and s = 7.5 . Consider an American call option with an expiration time T = 0.25 and a strike price K = 31 . By the
American call option pricing formula, we effectively calculate out that the price is 0.2244 .

Paper: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Jin-Peng-16/publication/228465614_A_new_option_pricing_model_for_stocks_in_uncertainty_markets/links/00b4952cb38e2c5ca2000000/A-new-option-pricing-model-for-stocks-in-uncertainty-markets.pdf

Comment: Have you looked at the sympy library? I'd suggest looking a the sympy integration tutorial https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorials/intro-tutorial/calculus.html?highlight=integration#integrals

Comment: Thanks for this doc. Now, I hope I will be able to integrate. But how to get the supremum first?

Comment: If you wrap the expression in a `Set` (in particular, maybe, a [`ConditionSet`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/sets.html#module-sympy.sets.conditionset)) it has a supremum method https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/sets.html#sympy.sets.sets.Set.sup.